# Insert elements of one list to another list recursively in Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I'm still learning the concept of recursion. 
I want to add elements of one list to the head of another list recursively while eliminating any duplicates. The code I used work fine for an atom. This is the code without recursion:

```
insert(H,L,[H|L]):-
   not(member(H,L)).
insert(H,L,L):-
   member(H,L).
```

However when I try recursion, I don't get the expected output. I understand I'm writing the insert/3 predicate wrong.

```
insert([H|T],[H1|T1],[H,H1|T1]):-
   not(member(H,[H1|T1])):-
   insert(T,[H,H1|T1],L).

insert([H|T],[H1|T1],[H1|T1]):-
   member(H,[H1|T1]),
   insert(T,[H1|T1],L).

insert([],L,L).
```

I'd appreciate any ideas on how to rectify the error in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Your original insert could be composed within another "insert_all" clause. For example...

```
% insert_all(NEW_ELEMENTS, LIST_TO_ADD_ELEMENTS_TO, OUTPUT)

insert_all([], O, O).
insert_all([X | T], I, O) :-
   insert(X, I, ITMP),
   insert_all(T, ITMP, O).
```

Example output:

```
1 ?- insert_all([a,b,c], [1,2,c], O).
O = [b, a, 1, 2, c].
```

You could also simplify `insert` to avoid having to do the `not(member(...))` check...

```
insert(H,L,L):-
   member(H,L), !.
insert(H,L,[H|L]).
```

The "cut" tells Prolog to not bother trying alternatives if preceding sub-clauses in the `insert` clause succeed. So if member fails, it will just do the second clause.